# what is the way to analyse specific schema queries in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Queries of multiple schemas of DB are logged in the `pg_log` directory in an application server, and the performance of specific schema needs to be profiled.

The same queries that are running, the difference is that `search_path` is set to include different schemas in each case.

How to log queries using a specific in `pg_log`? Or is there any way to "tail" specific the log for queries using a specific schema on the command line?

Comment: How do queries relate to schemas?

Comment: Meant that S1,S2 are two schemas in DB1.In general,  queries related to schemas are logged after "SET SESSION search_path TO 'S1'" and "SET SESSION search_path TO 'S2'"  respectively in pg_log.right?Requirement is monitoring schema 'S2' ( queries after SET SESSION search_path TO 'S2' alone) alone. @LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that.

What you could do is use different users to run the queries with different `search_path` settings, and then only log queries by a certain user:

```
ALTER ROLE myuser SET log_min_duration_statement = 0;
```